# Calling Java methods on button click, not refreshing JSP

Tags: java, ajax, jsp

I have 3 buttons in a JSP. I need each of these buttons to call a different Java method on-click, without refreshing the page. Searching around, it looks like I'll need servlets/AJAX, but I've never used either of these. It would be helpful if I could also call a respective JavaScript function when pressing a button, as well. The code I have now works for each button to call the proper method, but refreshes the page to do so.

My JSP code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.btn').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post("http://localhost:8080/PracticeProject/myservlet",
            {button: $(this).val()}).
            done(function( response ) {
                console.log(response);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <video id="myVideo" width="512" height="384" controls autoplay>
        <source id="videoPlayer" src="videos/Cold.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <form onsubmit="return false;" id="myForm">
        <button class="submit" value="button1">Button 1</button>
        <button class="submit" value="button2">Button 2</button>
        <button class="submit" value="button3">Button 3</button>
    </form>
    <button class="btn" value="button1">Button 1</button>
    <button class="btn" value="button2">Button 2</button>
    <button class="btn" value="button3">Button 3</button>
    <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/myservlet" method="post">
        <button type="submit" name="button" value="button1" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/myservlet" method="post">Button 1</button>
        <button type="submit" name="button" value="button2" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/myservlet" method="post">Button 2</button>
        <button type="submit" name="button" value="button3" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/myservlet" method="post">Button 3</button>
    </form>

    <script>



</body>
</html>
```

My Servlet code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class MyServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/myservlet")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public MyServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        String button = request.getParameter("button");
        System.out.println("In the servlet");

        if ("button1".equals(button)) {
            myClass.method1();
        } else if ("button2".equals(button)) {
            myClass.method2();
        } else if ("button3".equals(button)) {
            myClass.method3();
        } else {
            // ???
        }
    }

}
```

My Class code:

```
public class MyClass {

    public void method1(){
        // do method 1
        System.out.println("method 1");
    }
    public void method2(){
        // do method 2
        System.out.println("method 2");
    }
    public void method3(){
        // do method 3
        System.out.println("method 3");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pure AJAX or a framework such as jQuery. Here is a simple and very basic jQuery example which posts data to your servlet, but before it you will need a small modification in your HTML:

```
<form method="post">
        <button class="submit" value="button1">Button 1</button>
        <button class="submit" value="button2">Button 2</button>
        <button class="submit" value="button3">Button 3</button>
</form>
```

And then:

```
$('.submit').click(function(){
    $.post("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/myservlet", {button: $(this).val()}, function( data ) {
        alert( "Done!" );
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: These new buttons refresh the page but do not call the methods

Comment: Have you included jQuery in your page?

Comment: I've included <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> in the head of my JSP.

Comment: I made a small change in the JS code, also don't forget to include protocol section in your jQuery script address: `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I've edited my post to reflect the changes I've made to the JSP. Now I have 3 sets of buttons I am testing - the 1st does not refresh the page and does not reach the methods, the 2nd refreshes the page and does not reach the methods, and the 3rd redirects to a blank servlet page and does reach the methods. This is all the same when the commented-out JavaScript is uncommented.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax's Post Method to send the request to the server.
Firstly you should capture the form's submit event and prevent the default submit because of which the page gets reloaded. 
Secondly remove 
 `request.getRequestDispatcher("/theJSP.jsp").forward(request, response);`
because your server will return the html code if you are doing an ajax request.

Below is the updated ajax code, with the click handler, instead of form submit

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button class="btn" value="button1">Button 1</button>
<button class="btn" value="button2">Button 2</button>
<button class="btn" value="button3">Button 3</button>
</body>
<script>
$('.btn').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
        $.post("http://localhost:8080/PracticeProject/myservlet",
                 {button: $(this).val()}).
                done(function( response ) {
                    console.log(response);
                });
            });
    </script>
```

This is working at my end perfectly. Please make sure your web server is running.

Comment: I currently have 2 sets of buttons: my originals and the ones posted in the other answer. I removed the getRequestDispatcher and the original buttons now link to a blank servlet page. The new buttons stay on the right page, but reset the playing video and do not appear to reach the methods (which for right now simply print to the console)

Comment: I have edited the code. In case you still have queries let me know. Hope it helps.

Comment: I have commands to print to the console in the Java methods I am trying to call. This solution does not refresh the page, but is also not printing to the console, so I believe it is for some reason not reaching the methods still.

Comment: In the url of post method write the url directly instead of using page context. The url is not being called check the network tab of your browser whether the url returns 200 OK

Comment: Still not printing, I've updated the code in the original post.

Comment: What is the value you are getting in servlet’s String button ?

Comment: It doesn't appear to even be reaching the servlet because it is not printing "In the servlet" when I press those buttons

Comment: I have updated the code and the request is going to the servlet. Please check your server is running.